# Mac OS, LLVM 3.7 and missing math.h header

Tags: haskell, llvm

I need to use older version of LLVM on my Mac OS 10.12, namely 3.7 because it is required by `ghc`.

I have installed it via: `brew install llvm@3.7`.

Now I am getting the `<stdin>:1:10: fatal error: 'math.h' file not found` error when I do even the simplest thing:

```
echo '#include <math.h>' | clang-3.7 -xc -v -
```

Real code that produces this error is my attempt to run `ghc -fllvm` on a simple helloworld.hs code which I want to get as LLVM bitcode.

I have done:

```
$ find /usr/local/Cellar/llvm\@3.7 | grep math
/usr/local/Cellar/llvm@3.7/3.7.1/lib/llvm-3.7/include/c++/v1/cmath
/usr/local/Cellar/llvm@3.7/3.7.1/lib/llvm-3.7/include/c++/v1/ctgmath
/usr/local/Cellar/llvm@3.7/3.7.1/lib/llvm-3.7/include/c++/v1/tgmath.h
/usr/local/Cellar/llvm@3.7/3.7.1/lib/llvm-3.7/lib/clang/3.7.1/include/tgmath.h
```

I am seeing that there is no any `math.h` headers.

```
$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.0.2
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have realized what was my mistake: I should have looked missing `math.h` in C headers, not C++ headers.

Adding either of the following to the C compiler flags in `/usr/local/Cellar/ghc/8.0.2/lib/ghc-8.0.2/settings` fixes the problem:

`-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk`

or

`-idirafter /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/`